# How can I get the path of currently playing media in kmplayer and winamp?

Tags: c#, winamp

I want to write an application (in c#) that will begin when the kmplayer or winamp starts playing a video, and that needs to know the path of the video file, how can I do that?

**Edit:**
After some searching, coding and testing now I can do this using [sharpamp](https://github.com/Daniel15/Sharpamp) wrapper, all things while I'm opening my media file with winamp is ok but with kmplayer the filename is always empty.
My plugin code for getting filename is looks like this:

```
public class ThePlugin : GeneralPlugin
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Winamp.CurrentSong.Filename))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Winamp.CurrentSong.Filename);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File name is empty. ");
        }
    }
}
```

the result using km is "File name is empty."
In the *Winamp* class of *sharpamp*, there's a method named "UpdateSongData" that contains this line of code:

```
string filename = SendIPCCommandString(IPCCommand.GetFilename);
```

this code is for getting filename of playing media, so may be the IPC command of "GetFilename" (here it is: 3031) in this two player was different from each other?
Or the problem is another thing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's an easier approach, but you could try repeatedly doing something like this for winamp (completely untested):

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winamp");
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    string winampTitle = p.MainWindowTitle;

    // Check the title to see if it contains a video filename, and do
    // something with it..
}
```

Comment: With this approach, my application(or another) needs to be open always, and I don't want that.
Furthermore, I don't want the title of km or winamp. I want the file name of playing video!

Comment: The window title should contain the name of the currently playing file.

Comment: This code gives me the name of playing file. I want the file address of playing media!